# Link tag and media attribute

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm going through a training video on responsive design (lynda dot com). The instructor showed how to link an html doc to 2 different external css files that have screen size-specific formatting. In one example, he wrote the syntax for the medium size screen as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)" href="css/screen_layout_medium.css" />
```

The media attribute property is in double quotes. However, when i did this in Dw CS6, the html file wouldn't link to it. I then changed it to single quotes and it worked, but I don't know why. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Are you sure the quotes were plain, straight quotes?

Comment: The video shows double quotes. The instructor also said he was typing double quotes. I was racking my head as to why the html wouldn't link up. In the end I tried single quotes and saved the file. Dreamweaver immediately showed this css file being linked. I then refreshed the browsers and all worked like it was supposed to.

Comment: Yeah, but my question was if you were sure you had typed straight quotes `""` in the source rather than fancy smart quotes `“”` or the like.

Comment: Definitely used straight quotes. Btw, I just opened up my html file and changed the single quotes back to double and now it's working(???) Yesterday when I had this problem, I spent 15-20 minutes troubleshooting this - saving all the files, refreshing Dw and the browsers, removing the media attribute, adding it back in, closing Dw, reopening Dw, etc, etc and it just wouldn't work. Crazy...